# DIV Margin is not working as per requirements

Tags: html, css

I got confused in a very small problem and even though I know I am definitely doing something wrong. 
I took two divs with different CSS.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="internal">
        hii
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS of "main" id is

```
#main
{
    height:80px;
    background-color:black;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

and CSS of "internal" id is

```
#internal
{
    height:40px;
    background-color:red; 
    margin-top:30px
}
```

Here is JSFiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/h3sB9/)

margin-top in internal div is working only if there is border property in main div. If I remove border from main div then it is working differently. I am not getting whats happening here. Can anyone please answer my question?

Comment: What you want is padding-top. Margin works outside of the border. Padding is on the inside.

Comment: Technically there is nothing wrong with his method &mdash; it's just that vertical margins tend to collapse under certain situations. If he used the method of horizontal margins, the same issue will not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is a case of [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) (alternatively, read the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties) for a more detailed explanation). This happens when:

1. Vertical margins are adjacent (be it siblings or parent–child)
2. Empty element blocks

You should try to use padding on `#main` instead, i.e.:

```
#main {
    height:80px;
    background-color:black;
    border:1px solid green;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Padding on `#main`, that is

Comment: Thanks for this great info Terry.